# Python - MongoDB TypeError: find() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm searching through a MongoDB database to find a collection and pass it to another function that prints it to a file.

The name of my collection is: `ec2_list_01122021`

When I pass that collection to mongo db from a function called `print_collections()`, it complains that the `find()` command takes at least 1 argument:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\important_folders\Project\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 533, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\important_folders\Project\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 522, in main
    print_reports(interactive,aws_account,aws_account_number)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\important_folders\Project\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 432, in print_reports
    mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number,instance_col)
  File "C:\Users\tdun0002\OneDrive - Company\Desktop\important_folders\Project\git\cloud_scripts\aws_scripts\python\aws_tools\ec2_mongo.py", line 279, in mongo_export_to_file
    mongo_docs = instance_col.find()
TypeError: find() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

This is my code for print_collections():

```
def print_collections():
    myclient = connect_db()
    message = f"* Print DB Collections *"
    banner(message, border="*")
    print(f"This command prints the database collection names.\n")
    if myclient != None:
        # the list_database_names() method returns a list of strings
        database_names = myclient.list_database_names()
        print ("There are", len(database_names), "databases.")
        for db_num, db in enumerate(database_names):
            print ("\nGetting collections for database:", db, "--", db_num)
            collection_names = myclient[db].list_collection_names()
            print ("The MongoDB database returned", len(collection_names), "collections.")
            # iterate over the list of collection names
            for col_num, col in enumerate(collection_names):
                print (col, "--", col_num)
```

In my output I printed the value of the variable holding the collection name, so i don't know why the find command isn't working:

```
Enter the date in format 'dd/mm/yyyy': 01/12/2021
Input date is valid: 01/12/2021
Instance Collection: ec2_list_01122021 # <--- the collection that I'm passing to MongoDB
Interactive: 0
```

If I call the `mongo_export_to_file()` function directly from within this script and others, it does work. This is my `mongo_export_to_file()` function:

```
def set_db():
    myclient = connect_db()
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m%d%Y")
    mydb = myclient["aws_inventories"]
    instance_col = "ec2_list_" + today
    instance_col = mydb[instance_col]
    return mydb, instance_col
def mongo_export_to_file(interactive, aws_account, aws_account_number,instance_col=None):
    create_directories()
    today = datetime.today()
    today = today.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    if not instance_col:
        _, _, instance_col = set_db()
        print(f"Instance Collection: {instance_col}\nInteractive: {interactive}")
        time.sleep(10)
    # make an API call to the MongoDB server
    if interactive == 0:
        print(f"Instance Collection: {instance_col}\nInteractive: {interactive}")
        time.sleep(10)
        mongo_docs = instance_col.find()
    else:
        mongo_docs = instance_col.find({"Account Number": aws_account_number})
    docs = pandas.DataFrame(mongo_docs)
    docs.pop("_id")
    output_dir = os.path.join("..", "..", "output_files", "aws_instance_list", "csv", "")
    output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "aws-instance-master-list-" + today +".csv")
```

These are the collections in MongoDB:

```
> use aws_inventories
switched to db aws_inventories
> show collections
ec2_list_01082021
ec2_list_01112021
ec2_list_01122021
```

I'm naming the collections this way so they can be retrieved by date.

The purpose of the `print_reports()` function is to print reports for old entries from the database. By default the `mongo_export_to_file()` function prints a report for today's entry and that works fine.

Why can't mongodb find the collection name if I pass it into the function?

Comment: Find meethod needs, at least, the query. If you want to retrieve all DB use `find({})`

Comment: yeah I know. I am passing the collection to the function. And I print out the name of the collection in the output to make sure that the collection name is there and it's valid. I put that in the OP. What I don't know is thy the find() command isn't working if I pass the collection into the function.

Comment: Also I don't want to retrieve the entire database. I just  want to  print the contents of one collection representing one day.

Comment: In these lines in the original post I print the collection name just before the attempt to `find()` it: `print(f"Instance Collection: {instance_col}\nInteractive: {interactive}")
        time.sleep(10)
        mongo_docs = instance_col.find()`